# Search a PDF for a specific phrase

Tags: pdf, search

Is there a way to search the text of PDFs? For example I want to be taken to the page with the word "dog" and have it highlighted? I can't find a way with Amazon Kindle or ezPDF reader. Initially I made this question app specific but at this point I don't care; I will use any app that can search PDFs.

The PDF can be searched on my desktop computer.

Comment: Amazon Kindle App does not support PDF search. Its only applicable for your kindle ebooks.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the PDF, if it is searchable or not, for [ezPDF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader) does have a [search](http://www.unidocs.com/download/ezPDF_Reader_%28Android%29_Brief_Guide.pdf) function that highlight the searched text, as you can see in the image below:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

And there are many other applications that can highlight a searched text in PDF, like [Adobe Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader), [MoonReader+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader), [Quickoffice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quickoffice.android), etc.